# SDK expecting to be assigned a Frame value C#

Tags: c#, wpf, frame

I am using the Particle Setup SDK, where I call a method which requires me to assign a value to

```
public Frame AppFrame { get; set; }
```

However, I am unsure what value I am supposed to assign it.

```
AppFrame = //What value am I meant to assign to it, a window.xaml,
           //that contains a method of type Frame?
```

I tried to assign it a Window with a method called `public Frame particleframe()` although it is giving me the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.Frame' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame'`. So I tried to directly assign it the correct library:

```
public Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame particleframe()
```

Unfortunately this didn't work as type `UI` doesn''t exist. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why hapens if you try to do `AppFrame = new Frame();`?

Comment: I get the error code: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.Frame' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame'. I am having trouble implementing this library into my project, because the one it's requesting is a UWP library, meant for a UWP Project and I'm developing a WPF Project (I'm pretty sure).

Comment: have you tried `AppFrame = new System.Windows.Controls.Frame();`? If you're having problem with two namespaces with the same name you can always put an alias in the using statement of one of them. For example: `using WinControls = System.Windows.Controls;` and you can use it like this: `AppFrame = new WinControls.Frame();`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me, it wants the library Windows.UI.Xaml.Control.Frame, however it doesnt exist in my project. I cannot workout how, or even if its possible to add this library to a WPF project, as I think these controls are only designed for UWP projects

Comment: There's a [nuget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started) package for `Microsoft.UI.Xaml`. Are you using VS2015 or VS2017?

Comment: I am using VS2017

Comment: Have you used nuget before? If you haven't, you have to right click in the project where you want to add the library. Then select Manage NuGet Packages. In the new window you have a "Browse" tab, select it and search for `Windows.UI.Xaml`. Select the package and install it.If the installation worked now you can use the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` library.

Comment: Yeah I have used it before, got multiple packages in my current project. Will give this a go and let you know, thanks for your help.

Comment: @ikerbera Unfortunately that package isn't compatible with the .NETFramework Version 4.6.1, so I cannot install it.

Comment: The Error: Could not install package 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: That means that the lib `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml` is targeting a  lower version of .Net. You should search wich version is targeting, then create a test project in that .Net version and add the package. If that works you should think about changing .Net versions on your main project.